# zsh tcsh-like history navigation

Tags: zsh, command-history, line-editor

In `tcsh`, the `\eP` and `\eN` commands take into account the whitespace-normalized prefix of the current line, not just the first word.

For instance if my history contains

```
git pull upstream feature-dancing-pigs
git clone
```

and I type

```
% git pull
```

and then hit `\eP` in `tcsh`, I get

```
% git pull upstream feature-dancing-pigs
```

if I hit `\eP` in `zsh`, I get a history item that just matches the command

```
% git clone
```

I want to configure `zsh` to emulate the `tcsh` behavior. Is it possible?

I've tried `zsh` with the default emacs key configuration and with an explicit

```
bindkey "\eP" history-search-backward
```

As it turns out

```
bindkey "\eP" history-beginning-search-backward
```

does have the expected behavior I was just using `^[` initially in place of `\e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function documented in `zshcontrib` called `up-line-or-beginning-search`, you can view this by running.

```
man zshcontrib | less '+/^\s*up-line-or-beginning-search'
```

> These widgets are similar to the builtin functions up-line-or-search and down-line-or-search:  if in a multiline buffer they move up
>                 or  down within the buffer, otherwise they search for a history line matching the start of the current line.  In this case, however,
>                 they search for a line which **matches the current  line  up  to  the  current  cursor  position**,  in  the  manner  of  history-begin‐
>                 ning-search-backward and -forward, **rather than the first word on the line**.

if you look at the instructions given at the top of the `ZLE FUNCTIONS` section in `man zshcontrib`

> ZLE FUNCTIONS
>      Widgets
>          These  functions  all  implement  user-defined  ZLE widgets (see zshzle(1)) which can be bound to keystrokes in interactive shells.  To use
>          them, your .zshrc should contain lines of the form
>   `autoload function`
>   `zle -N function`

Personally I have followed the instructions above, but I suspect nowadays you may not need to...
in your `~/.zshrc`

```
# register the function with the autoloader
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
# define new zle widget
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
# bind UP key
[[ -n "${key[Up]}" ]] && bindkey "${key[Up]}" up-line-or-beginning-search
```

Comment: Also, I just now figured out that the syntax I was using originally had no chance of working. The syntax for a literal escape in zsh is `\e`. it appears that `history-beginning-search-backward` actually does do what I intended and mimics the `tcsh` behavior.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet glad you got it working. I wondered what the `^[` and other sequence your mentioned were referring to. I assumed `UP`. I believe these sequences are different from one terminal to another. Also I suspect  "\eP" is not a literal escape sequence but a zsh syntactic sugar that produces UP in a terminal agnostic way, so you don't need to deal with the literal characters. But I should ask a question about this as I'm  a bit unsure myself.

Comment: The existing organization of this question doesn't make much sense since I made an assumption about the syntax for binding keys in `zsh` that turned out to be wrong. It's also not immediately clear to me how 'up-line-or-beginning-search' differs from 'history-beginning-search-or-backward' (I don't have it in my zshcontrib)

Comment: @GregoryNisbet good points. The reason I gave `up-line-or-beginning-search` as an answer, and how it differs from `history-beginning-search-or-backward` is that once you bind <UP> to a search you lose the ability to move up a line in a zsh multiline buffer. So I don't - consider `history-beginning-search-or-backward` to be a long-term solution. At some point you might want to use multiline buffers. This is a huge feature of zsh. I just wrote a multiline heredoc command with zsh 5 minutes ago. so you might need to "upgrade" to `up-line-or-beginning-search` anyway.

Comment: this is totally the wrong place for this question, but what is a multiline buffer and where is it documented? when I try to write a heredoc starting with `sh <<EOF` for instance, my arrow keys show me things from my history. I didn't bind them specifically but am using `bindkey -e`.

Comment: exactly - thats the problem with `history-beginning-search-or-backward`, you lose the normal behaviour of the `<UP>` key. I suggest if you want to find out more about the mulitline commands check out this [intro to zsh by Seth House](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6hJ8Nqjgv8), google it and then if you you get stuck, you could ask a new question here unix.se